# Equivalent of "continue" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, keyword, continue

In C and many other languages, there is a `continue` keyword that, when used inside of a loop, jumps to the next iteration of the loop. Is there any equivalent of this `continue` keyword in Ruby?

Comment: continue doesn't "restart" the loops but jumps to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: @mlaw: I edited my question accordingly to prevent future confusion.

Comment: @dbr the duplicate you've found was asked after this one.

Answer (score 1077, accepted):

Yes, it's called `next`.

```
for i in 0..5
   if i < 2
     next
   end
   puts "Value of local variable is #{i}"
end
```

This outputs the following:

```
Value of local variable is 2
Value of local variable is 3
Value of local variable is 4
Value of local variable is 5
 => 0..5
```

Comment: This is how I remember--Ruby respects Perl (`next`) above C (`continue`)

Comment: ProTip: Careful using it with `and` like `puts "Skipping" and next if i < 2` because `puts` returns `nil`, which is "falsey", and so `next` won't get called.

Answer (score 128):

`next`

also, look at `redo` which redoes the *current* iteration.

Comment: ... cause ruby is rad like that.

Comment: Ruby borrowed much from Perl, including Perl's [`redo`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html) command (or its essence, anyway). For Ruby's interpretation, search for "redo" within [this page](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.5/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html).

Answer (score 110):

Writing [*Ian Purton's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010063/261542) in a slightly more idiomatic way:

```
(1..5).each do |x|
  next if x < 2
  puts x
end
```

Prints:

```
  2
  3
  4
  5
```

Answer (score 44):

Inside for-loops and iterator methods like `each` and `map` the `next` keyword in ruby will have the effect of jumping to the next iteration of the loop (same as `continue` in C).

However what it actually does is just to return from the current block. So you can use it with any method that takes a block - even if it has nothing to do with iteration.

Comment: as well as nice redo statement

Answer (score 34):

Ruby has two other loop/iteration control keywords: `redo` and `retry`. 
[Read more about them, and the difference between them, at Ruby QuickTips](http://rubyquicktips.tumblr.com/post/1122838559/redo-vs-retry).

Answer (score 10):

I think it is called [next](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use next, it will bypass that condition and rest of the code will work.
Below i have provided the Full script and out put

```
class TestBreak
  puts " Enter the nmber"
  no= gets.to_i
  for i in 1..no
    if(i==5)
      next
    else 
      puts i
    end
  end
end

obj=TestBreak.new()
```

Output:
 Enter the nmber
10

1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
10

Answer (score 1):

Use may use next conditionally

```rb
before = 0
"0;1;2;3".split(";").each.with_index do |now, i|
    next if i < 1
    puts "before it was #{before}, now it is #{now}"
    before = now
end
```

output:

```
before it was 0, now it is 1
before it was 1, now it is 2
before it was 2, now it is 3
```