# Iterate through an array and list all but one item

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, erb

I have an array of items that I want to list, but there is one specific item called 'tip' that I would like to exclude. I was thinking of something like "unless item.name == 'tip'" but aren't sure where to place something like that

```
<ul>
  <% @order.each do |item| %>
    <li><h2><%= item["quantity"] %> &times; <%= item["name"] %></h2></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `unless .. end` inside `<% .. %>`:

```
<ul>
  <% @order.each do |item|
       unless item['name'] == 'tip' %>
    <li><h2><%= item["quantity"] %> &times; <%= item["name"] %></h2></li>
  <%   end
     end %>
</ul>
```

---

Example (used `item['name']` instead of `item.name` for brevity):

```
require 'erb'

class Listing
  def build
    @order = [
      {'quantity' => 1, 'name' => 'a'},
      {'quantity' => 2, 'name' => 'tip'},
      {'quantity' => 3, 'name' => 'c'},
    ]

    template = ERB.new <<-TMPL
    <ul>
      <% @order.each do |item|
           unless item['name'] == 'tip'%>
        <li><h2><%= item["quantity"] %> &times; <%= item["name"] %></h2></li>
      <%   end
         end %>
    </ul>
    TMPL
    template.result binding
  end
end

puts Listing.new.build
```

output:

```
<ul>

    <li><h2>1 &times; a</h2></li>

    <li><h2>3 &times; c</h2></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: When I do that I get the following error: (erb):10: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end ; _erbout.force_encoding(__ENCODING__) ^

Comment: @Agis I noticed the double <% end %> and only had one, but I still receive that same error. I'm not quite sure why...

Comment: @csakon There must be a syntax error somewhere else in your file. The answer's code is fine. Can you post the whole file?

Comment: @Agis, Why did you remove `end` (without edit comment) ?

Comment: @Agis I still get this error - undefined method `name' for {"quantity"=>1, "item"=>"The Maine Event"}:Hash

Comment: @csakon, The code in your question contains ` item.name == 'tip' `. Maybe you mean `item['name'] == 'tip'` ?  I change the code accordingly.

Comment: @csakon, I'm not Agis. You don't need to tag my username when you comment to my answer.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Thank you to @falsetru

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of possibilities to achieve a goal. I would suggest to use [`next`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010039/equivalent-of-continue-in-ruby) keyword since it gives you an ability to forget circumstances in the latter code, plus it does not require an enclosing `end` keyword (when you have more code lines under the condition, it quickly becomes hard to take a glance on where `unless … end` clause begins/ends):

```
<ul>
  <% @order.each do |item|
       next if item["name"] == 'tip' %>
    <li><h2><%= item["quantity"] %> &times; <%= item["name"] %></h2></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: I receive this error when I try your code : undefined method `name' for {"quantity"=>1, "item"=>"The Maine Event"}:Hash