# how to skip certain line in text file and keep reading the next line in python?

Tags: python

I have been searching for this answer but did not quite get it.

I have a text file that looks like this

```
who are you????
who are you man?
who are you!!!!
who are you? man or woman?
```

I want to skip the line with `man` in it and print

```
who are you????
who are you!!!!
```

My code so far

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
word = "man"
for line in f:
    if word in line:
        f.next()
    else:
        print line
```

This prints the first line only

```
who are you????
```

How should I troubleshoot this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why call `f.next()`. Simply `if word not in line: print line`. You don't have to do anything if `word` is in the `line`.

Comment: Printing the first line is not the only problem. Your code also raises an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not necessary to add an `if else` statement in `for` loop, so you can modify your code in this way:

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
word = "man"
for line in f:
    if not word in line:
        print line
```

Furthermore, the issue in your code is that you are using `f.next()` directly in a for loop used to scan the file. This is the reason because when the line contains "man" word, your code skips two lines.

If you want preserve `if else` statement because this is only an example of a more complex problem, you can use the following code:

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
word = "man"
for line in f:
    if word in line:
        continue
    else:
        print line
```

Using `continue`, you skip one loop's iteration, and so you can reach your goal.

As Alex Fung suggests, would be better use `with`, so your code would become like this:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as test_file:
    for line in test_file:
        if "man" not in line:
            print line
```

Comment: An explanation of *why* the `next()` is the problem would be useful.

Comment: I suggest using `with` to make sure the file object is closed at the end,

Comment: Interesting to see how our answers almost converged after multiple edits. You get my vote!

Comment: Thank you for the help. You are right, this is just an example for more complex problem. Indeed `continue` is what I've been searching for.

Comment: @Fang: Don't forget to use `print line,` You'll end up with too many newlines otherwise

Comment: Glad to help you! Anyway, please consider to use with instead open.

Answer (score 5):

## Problem

With your current code, when the current line contains `"man"` :

- you don't print anything. That's correct.
- you also skip the next line. That's your problem!
- `f.next()` is already called implicitely by `for line in f:` at each iteration. So you actually call `f.next()` twice when "man" is found.
- If the last line of your file contains a `"man"`, Python will throw an exception because there's no next line.

You might have been looking for [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue), which would also achieve the desired result but would be complex and unneeded. Note that it's called [`next`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010063/6419007) in Perl and Ruby, which might be confusing.

## Example

```
who are you????            # <- This line gets printed, because there's no "man" in it
who are you man?           # word in line is True. Don't print anything. And skip next line
who are you!!!!            # Line is skipped because of f.next()
who are you? man or woman? # word in line is True. Don't print anything. 
                           #   Try to skip next line, but there's no next line anymore.
                           #   The script raises an exception : StopIteration
```

## Correct code

Don't forget to close the file. You can do this automatically with `with` :

```
word = "man"
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if not word in line:
            print line, # <- Note the comma to avoid double newlines
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I've been searching for `continue` and the answer from you and the next answer help me to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
word = "man"
for line in f:
    if not word in line:
        print line
```